# PROFTPD how can i deny upload of Non-ASCII Characters files

Tags: file-upload, non-ascii-characters, proftpd

**PROFTPD**

how can i deny upload of Non-ASCII Characters files 
so users can not upload files with illegal Characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i can use PathAllowFilter

PathAllowFilter ^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$